# Too minor but valid edit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

As I understand, the reasons for discouraging too minor edits are that they can swamp the review queue, and block the post from actual improvement edits. Still, I often see edits that just change "i'm" to "I'm", which I reject.

But the thing is that the damage is already done: it is taking space in the queue and blocking the edits; and it is certainly improving the post (even thought very slightly). So, I suggest a new rejection reason: **Too minor, but valid**.

These changes are simple to spot, so only two reviewers should be enough, so we get them out of the way quickly. They do improve the post, so they will be applied; but to not encourage the behaviour, the editor will not get the reputation and it will count as a rejected edit.

Comment: You can always use 'improve' and uncheck the 'helpful' box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Too minor` already indicates it is valid. Else it would have been an `Invalid edit`. When improving the post, can edit the post at will, leaving the `Helpful` checkbox checked or unchecked depending on the usefulness of the edit.

Hence, I see no need for your feature request.

Comment: Do users still get +2 reputation if an edit was approved, but not helpful?

Comment: Not helpful = no. It counts as a declined suggested edit.

Comment: @JeremieMiserez Yup, what Patrick said. Not Helpful is a rejection.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks, I wasn't able to find this information anywhere.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Good to know that. Maybe it should be more advertised, maybe I haven't read the docs carefully enough.